# How to edit scale in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the `gapminder` data set.  I would like to change the scale on the population legend so instead of scientific notation, each number is multiplied by .00001.  Any suggestions?

```
gapminder1 <- gapminder %>% 
  filter(country != "Kuwait")


ggplot(gapminder1) +
  geom_point(aes(lifeExp, gdpPercap, size = pop, color = continent)) +
  facet_wrap(~ year, nrow = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "sqrt") +
  labs(title = "Plot to recreate",
       size = "Population (100k)",
       color = "Cotinent") +
  xlab("Life Expectancy") +
  ylab("GDP per Capita") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  # theme(legend.title = element_text("Continent")) +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)
options(scipen = 99)

gapminder1 <- gapminder %>% 
  filter(country != "Kuwait")


ggplot(gapminder1) +
  geom_point(aes(lifeExp, gdpPercap, size = pop*.00001, color = continent)) +
  facet_wrap(~ year, nrow = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "sqrt") +
  labs(title = "Plot to recreate",
       size = "Population (100k)",
       color = "Cotinent") +
  xlab("Life Expectancy") +
  ylab("GDP per Capita") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `labels = scales::unit_format()`:

```
ggplot(gapminder1) +
  geom_point(aes(lifeExp, gdpPercap, size = pop, color = continent)) +
  facet_wrap(~ year, nrow = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "sqrt") +
  scale_size_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(unit = "", scale = .00001)) +
  labs(title = "Plot to recreate",
       size = "Population (100k)",
       color = "Cotinent") +
  xlab("Life Expectancy") +
  ylab("GDP per Capita") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

There is a `sep =`  argument if you don't like the space.